# Build fails intermittently on Jenkins node machine

Tags: jenkins

I created a build system on windows 2019 server where I installed Jenkins version 2.375.1 and which is running Java 17. I am completely new in this and doing it for first time.

Here is the issue: Whenever I run any job, sometime s(4-6 out of 10) it fails by throwing an exception. See below :

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at jenkins.agents.WebSocketAgents$Session.closed(WebSocketAgents.java:153)
at jenkins.websocket.WebSockets$1.onWebSocketClose(WebSockets.java:80)
at jenkins.websocket.Jetty10Provider$2.onWebSocketClose(Jetty10Provider.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.JettyWebSocketFrameHandler.notifyOnClose(JettyWebSocketFrameHandler.java:308)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.JettyWebSocketFrameHandler.onClosed(JettyWebSocketFrameHandler.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.core.internal.WebSocketCoreSession.lambda$closeConnection$0(WebSocketCoreSession.java:272)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1487)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.core.server.internal.AbstractHandshaker$1.handle(AbstractHandshaker.java:212) 
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.core.internal.WebSocketCoreSession.lambda$closeConnection$1(WebSocketCoreSession.java:272)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Callback$4.completed(Callback.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Callback$Completing.succeeded(Callback.java:344)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.JettyWebSocketFrameHandler.onError(JettyWebSocketFrameHandler.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.core.internal.WebSocketCoreSession.lambda$closeConnection$2(WebSocketCoreSession.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1468)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:1487)
............
............
............
```

And the log I got in node machine on console is :

```
INFO: Connected
Jan 15, 2023 8:05:02 AM hudson.remoting.UserRequest perform
WARNING: LinkageError while performing 
UserRequest:hudson.node_monitors.SwapSpaceMonitor$MonitorTask@4c55cc1c
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\test*****\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--202642030\jna2121667260400486382.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2389)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1045)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:1015)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:221)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.setAlignType(Structure.java:291)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:208)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:204)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:191)
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:183)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.Windows$MEMORYSTATUSEX.<init>(Windows.java:67)
```

Some more info about configuration :

1. Both controller and node machine is windows server 2019
2. Since in latest Jenkins the java web connect(Run Jenkins as service on node) is not available so directly running the agent command in node's CLI.
3. Both controller and node is running Java v17
   [image: Java version]

I went through couple of links and tried all the possible suggestion provided like power management settings on salve machine, increasing Jenkins build timeout settings etc... but no luck.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a bug in Jenkins itself or something. I could not find the answer of the exact issue but after making some changes in jenkins configuration, now i am able to run all the jobs without getting above exception.

Here it is : Earlier i checked jenkins to use websocket in slave configuration. If i just disable it and run then not getting any issue.

[image]

Just disbaling this worked for me.. Thanks.